# Extract public key from a DER encoded X.509 Cert using node-forge and Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, amazon-kms, node-forge

I have an asymmetric key created in AWS KMS. I am trying to obtain it's public key using Javascript. To do that, I use the `GetPublicKey` [API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/client/kms/command/GetPublicKeyCommand/) that comes with the `aws-sdk`.
In the API's response, the public key is returned as an `Uint8Array` which represents a

> a DER-encoded X.509 public key, also known as SubjectPublicKeyInfo
> (SPKI), as defined in RFC 5280

I am trying to retrieve the public key string from this object, so that I can use that for further encryption.

My code looks like below

```
import * as forge from 'node-forge';
import { GetPublicKeyCommand, KMSClient  } from "@aws-sdk/client-kms";    
function getPublicKeyFromKMS() {
        const response = await kmsClient.send(new GetPublicKeyCommand(getKeyInput));
        const uIntArrayKey = response.PublicKey!;
        const bufferKey = Buffer.from(uIntArrayKey.buffer);
        const cert = forge.pki.certificateFromAsn1(forge.asn1.fromDer(new  forge.util.ByteStringBuffer(bufferKey), false ));
        console.log(cert.publicKey)
        return cert.publicKey;
    }
```

I use the `node-forge` module to get the certificate from the DER encoded response.

**My issue is** :
When I do `forge.asn1.fromDer(new  forge.util.ByteStringBuffer(bufferKey), false )` , I get the below error.

> > Error: Unparsed DER bytes remain after ASN.1 parsing.
> > at Object.asn1.fromDer (/Users/####/node_modules/node-forge/lib/asn1.js:460:17)
>
> > byteCount: 8192,
> > remaining: 8111

How do I make sure that I pass only the necessary bytes to the `fromDer()` function? Or How do I handle the remaining bytes to avoid this error?

Comment: I'm not quite clear on your question, but I assume by *...so that I can use that for further encryption...* you mean that you want to convert the public key into the node-forge internal format, i.e. import the public key. Please specify if it is an RSA or EC key by posting the Base64 encoded Uint8Array with the data. Since it is a public key, this is not problematic. Alternatively post a non-productive sample public key.